How to Address Moisture in Corner of Mudroom?
I moved into my new home relatively recently, and it has a lower "mud room" entrance under my main stairs that I've been tidying up (not looking to finish it, but make it more presentable). There was some moisture in there coming from the brick around it outside and the porch above it, so I spent some time sealing all of that up. I then re-painted the room, but was disappointed to see that some moisture was still bleeding through one of the corners of the room and discoloring the paint. It's also leaving just a little condensation in that corner.
I assume it's bleeding in from the foundation outside, where the corner of that mudroom is under about 6 of dirt. I did some re-grading of the dirt on that side (which was needed) in hopes of stopping the water, but it still seems to be getting some moisture. Not a huge deal and I doubt it's going to matter much given that it's all exterior to my actual home, but I'd like advice on how to address.
I assume the "right" way would be to dig down the six feet and re-seal the exterior blocks. There is also foam insulation board bordering the brick outside so I assume I'd probably have to tear that up as I dig and replace that too? Sounds like a decent amount of work and not super accessible with a gutter line running through there and a bush right next to it, but if there's no better/easier way to stop the moisture then OK.
Here are pictures showing the situation. Advice appreciated!
https://imgur.com/a/zF4wCEi

water/ moisture must be sealed from the outside.  Trying to seal inside only makes the water seek another exit point.

Grading and making sure downspouts drain away is good, but sealing from outside is the best.

"Oh, damp spot in the corner! Thou are not welcome in mine house! Begone, never to return!"

Thanks all. @crip659 - Any idea if there's a certain amount of time it takes to "dry out" the block to see if my grading did the trick? I just did the grading last weekend and it seems like there might be a bit less moisture coming through, so I don't want to over-react and start digging if maybe what I did already did the trick.

Sure, give it a couple of weeks and several rainstorms (which may take more than a couple of weeks, depending.) I've occasionally had sucess with (while expecting nothing but the price of a can down the drain) throwing drylok at a basement leak, but since you've already painted with something else, I don't know if it would stand any chance of working,  without aggressive removal of previous paint first. And it might not work at all, because sealing the inside is indeed low odds of success.

Thanks, @ecnerwal. Actually, the white paint in the picture is Drylok Exteme so I was also attempting the ol' Drylok hail mary! I did scrape as much of the old paint as I could but I won't say I achieved perfect adherence (especially in that corner). I'll wait a few weeks and will hopefully see some moisture mitigation. Is another coat of Drylok sufficient to attempt to block those stains (assuming it dries out), or is something else better?
